# Run IIS as current user

Tags: asp.net-2.0

I have a security problem I can't solve.
I have developed web service that it is actually a wrapper for native dll api.
When I run it from ASP.NET Development server (From Visual Studio) there are no problems
(The visual studio runs as administrator)
The native DLL also create directories and files in the hard drive.
Now, when i use it with iis, since it doesn't has priviligies of writing directories and folders, and off course read data from registry it fails operationg.

So, how do I run IIS as administrator instead of built-in account?

Thanks,
Shay

Comment: Can you not just give the IIS user account the privileges that it needs?  Giving IIS full admin powers is a *massive* security risk.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an account with the appropriate permissions, and then have ASP.NET run your application using that account.  The steps to do that will vary somewhat depending on what version of IIS that you're running.

Comment: Well, I did it. Creating an account with proper priviligue, but now I do have a new problem.
The native DLL beside of the folders and file it creates, seems to open a new proccess for each folder it makes.
Why the IIS if it has the priviligue doesn't allow it to create new proccesses ?